# Magento load layout handle directive programmatically

Tags: magento-1.7, layout, order-email, renderer

In an e-mail template I found this *layout handle* which is displaying an *overview of purchased products*:

```
{{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order}}
```

I'm trying to load this layout handle somewhere in an encapsulated environment. But I don't know how to render the content. This is what I have made so far:

```
require '../app/Mage.php';
Mage::init();

ini_set('xdebug.var_display_max_depth', -1);
ini_set('xdebug.var_display_max_children', -1);
ini_set('xdebug.var_display_max_data', -1);

$orderId = 200001234;
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderId);

/* Rendering Layout Block, but how?! */
// echo {{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order}}
```

This is the XML-Defintion of the layout handle

```
<sales_email_order_items>
    <block type="sales/order_email_items" name="items" template="email/order/items.phtml">
        <action method="addItemRender"><type>default</type><block>sales/order_email_items_order_default</block><template>email/order/items/order/default.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>sales/order_email_items_order_grouped</block><template>email/order/items/order/default.phtml</template></action>
        <block type="sales/order_totals" name="order_totals" template="sales/order/totals.phtml">
            <action method="setLabelProperties"><value>colspan="3" align="right" style="padding:3px 9px"</value></action>
            <action method="setValueProperties"><value>align="right" style="padding:3px 9px"</value></action>
            <block type="tax/sales_order_tax" name="tax" template="tax/order/tax.phtml">
                <action method="setIsPlaneMode"><value>1</value></action>
            </block>
        </block>
    </block>
    <block type="core/text_list" name="additional.product.info" />
</sales_email_order_items>
```

Comment: That is not going to work there. Layouts are rendered by Magento's layout system, which is not available in your external file. You might need to replicate the logic of those template/block files in your external file. You can also try with making objects of block - template system, but not sure if it will work.

Comment: Have a look at this url:
http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-load-render-custom-layout-handle/

Comment: @mohit-kumar-arora: This solution on that page will only work from within a controller action. Any other thoughts?

Comment: Use $app = Mage::app(); and then replace $this with $app in your code.
Please let me know if it worked.
I have not checked it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following script in Magento root folder should do the trick.

```
require './app/Mage.php';
Mage::init();

$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId(200001234);


$layout = Mage::app()->getLayout();
$update = $layout->getUpdate();
$update->addHandle('default');
$update->addHandle('sales_email_order_items');

$update->load();

$layout->generateXml();
$layout->generateBlocks();
$layout->getBlock('root')->setTemplate('page/1column.phtml');

//set block from layout handle <block type="sales/order_email_items" name="items" template="email/order/items.phtml">
$layout->getBlock('content')->setChild('items', $layout->getBlock('items')); 

$layout->getBlock('content')->append('items');
$block = $layout->getBlock('items')->setData('order', $order );

echo $block->toHtml();
// or echo $layout->getOutput(); for whole layout output
```

It's important invoking the functions in the right order.
Means using the `load()`-function after `addHandle()` but before `getBlock()` calls.